# Generate a truth-table in Scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme, truthtable

The specification is given below:

```
(truth-table formula) --> truth-table
```

A formula is:

- a truth value i.e. either `#t` or `#f`
- a variable i.e `p, q, r, ...`
- `(not formula)`
- `(and formula1 formula2)`
- `(or formula1 formula2)`

A truth-table is set of rows. A row contains a binding `(I t)` where `I` is truth assignment i.e. the set of bindings `(p t)`. `I` must be:

- Consistent
- Complete

`t` is produced by the valuation function `V(formula, I)`. `V` is defined as:

- `V(t,I) = t`
- `V(p,I) = t` for a binding `(p t)` in `I`
- `V((not formula), I) = (not (V (formula I)))`
- `V((and formula1 formula2), I) = (and V(formula1 I) V(formula2 I))`
- `V(( or formula1 formula2), I) = (or V(formula1 I) V( formula2 I))`

What can be the procedure to follow in order to implement a truth-table in Scheme? Note that there may be subformulas inside a formula.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? in StackOverflow it's OK to ask specific questions regarding concrete problems in your code, but you shouldn't come empty-handed and expect people to write all of the code from scratch

Comment: Can you show an example truth-table, as well?  It's not entirely clear what the specification means.

Comment: Looks like you could make yorself an interpreter to do this. If you make the syntax lisp you don't need a parser.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a you need some sort of parser. First to extract the unique symbols from the expression and second to build the expression into a tree/nested list  form. Then iterate across the possible truth value combination to generate the truth table.